# Is there an equivalent of Netscape navigator functions in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Can I access the inbuilt navigator functions like isinNet() or DomainNameorHost() from nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nodeJS runs on the server, not the browser, you can't access functions that are only provided in a browser.

Most developers use a middleware like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) to create a web service on nodejs.

In a route, such as

```
app.route("/play", function(req,res){
   // code that handles URL /play
});
```

there is a `callback` function that is called when a request arrives for that route.

The `req` object parameter contains everything about the [request](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#req.params).

req.ip is the upstream (incoming) ip address.

I looked around in [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) for a module that might map remote ips to hostnames and could not find one. Presumably all it would do is reverseDNS, which could take time and hold up processing requests.